# Scipy cKDTree query_pairs versus query_ball_tree

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

I am a bit confused about the differences/similarities between the `query_pairs` and `query_ball_tree` methods of `Scipy`'s cKDTree.

Reading the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) we can see that they have the same description:

> **query_ball_tree(self, other, r[, p, eps])** - Find all pairs of points whose distance is at most r
>   **query_pairs(self, r[, p, eps])** - Find all pairs of points whose distance is at most r.

They even require the same *obligatory* parameters, except for `query_ball_tree` that asks for `other` which is (from [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_tree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_tree)): *"The tree containing points to search against."*.

So, **is there a practical difference between these two methods? Is it preferred to use one over the other?** I currently use `query_pairs` for my purposes, but I am considering alternatives to it.

I have seen people use the former something like `tree1.query_ball_tree(tree2, ...)`, which suggests that you can query between different trees... but I *guess* that it would be equivalent to `query_pairs` if we did something like `tree1.query_ball_tree(tree1, ...)`. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the possibility to search on two trees is the only difference here (but that's just an impression after a short code lookup). If you are considering alternatives (for whatever reason, you can always try sklearn's.)

Comment: @sascha thanks I will. Is it more capable of handling BIG numbers of points?

Comment: I can't give guarantees. The only thing i i can tell you: people (with a lot of experience) recommend sklean in the past stating scipy's implementation is worse. **But**: this was in the past and probably more related to kdtree. Not sure if things changed or not. sklearn is very well documented, easier to install than scipy, easy to use and reading the git history, there is a bit more action on the tree-stuff (hard to interpret). One of the core devs of sklearns implementation (jakevdp) is also part of scipy's author-list of improvements. Trying it can not hurt much.

Comment: @sascha thanks for the info :) I'll surely check that sklearn class, and compare it with cKDTree of scipy (which is already its C implementation as far as I know, so already efficient?). Thanks again, cheers.

Comment: As the mentioned person is also a SO-user, we can ask @jakevdp what we should expect comparing scipy's and sklearn's ball-tree implementation. (Yes, try it. The implementation language is probably not the most important issue in algorithmic-driven algorithms; but sklearn's implementation is at least cython-based too; to not sacrifice these constant speedups). If performance is not satisfying and approximate results can work, you can search for many alternatives, e.g. using this [benchmark](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks) of libs with a python interface (approx-libs more popular?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query_ball_tree` find all pairs of points between `self` and `other` whose distance is at most r.

`query_pairs` find all pairs of points in `self` whose distance is at most r.

These new official docs might help you:

- scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_tree — SciPy v1.6.0.dev Reference Guide http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_tree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_tree
- scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs — SciPy v1.6.0.dev Reference Guide http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_pairs